# MySQL Export script cannot be imported

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm quite familiar with SQL but new to MySQL... I exported a DB to a single .SQL file and now I can't import it due to reported security and syntax errors.

Here's an example from the export:

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `calcGameTotal`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `calcGameTotal`(IN  gid INT, OUT ct BIGINT(20))
BEGIN 
/*redacted*/ 
END$$
```

Firstly, I get complaints about lack of privileges with `DEFINER=root@localhost` which kind of makes sense since I'm not logged in as *root* - but I do have DROP/CREATE privileges.

Secondly, apparently `--` is breaking as a syntax error on import. In which case how is the procedure in the DB without problems, and exporting, in the first place?

I think this is all a problem of exporting/importing... I don't really want all that `DEFINER` stuff unless I have to for instance. I'm using phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench - can someone explain how I should go about understanding and fixing this?